# What are the Online Battle Soundtracks on X and Y

Tags: pokemon-x-y

What are the 11 Online Battle soundtracks on X and Y?

I know 7 is VS Team Flare Boss, and 11 is VS Champion, but that is it.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Seems a perfectly fair question to me with an exact answer (and useful too, considering the game only titles them Music 1, Music 2 etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Due to the nature of the songs' original use spoilers follow**

*Music 1 - 4 are also available in the Battle Maison*

Music 1 - Trainer Battle

Music 2 - Wild Pokémon Encounter

Music 3 - Rival Battle

Music 4 - Gym Leader Battle

*Music 5 - 11 are not available in the Battle Maison*

Music 5 - Successor Korrina Battle (Mega Lucario fight)

Music 6 - Team Flare Standard Battle

Music 7 - Team Flare Boss

Music 8 - Yvetal / Xerneas Encounter

Music 9 - Kanto Legendary Encounter

Music 10 - Elite 4 Battle

Music 11 - Kalos League Champion

Comment: Source http://www.serebii.net/xy/music.shtml

Answer (score 2):

As you progress through the story, you will find that on PSS, or the battle spot, will unlock music 5-11 when you encounter it.

Comment: This does not answer the question asked. I asked, what are the soundtracks, this is instead saying how to get it.